# What happens when a router receives an LSA with the same sequence nr?

Tags: ospf

What will break the tie in this case? Maybe the age timer? If so, the router has to choose the newer one, so I'd guess that it will prefer the age field with a smaller value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question. When a router encounters two instances of an LSA, it must determine which is more recent. An LSA is identified by its LS type, ID, and LSA router. For two instances of the same LSA, the LS sequence number, LS checksum, and LS age fields are used to determine which instance is more recent (thereby accounting for all the header fields). As per the standard:

1. The LSA having the newer LS sequence number is more recent.
2. If the two instances have different LS checksums, then the instance having the larger LS checksum (when considered as a 16-bit unsigned integer) is considered more recent.